# MVC Architecture in .Net6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, architecture, backend, .net-6.0

Basically I want to follow MVC Architecture. So should I use Asp.Net Web Api or Asp.Net MVC for backend development?

Does Asp.Net Web Api have MVC architecture? If does help me build Web Api using MVC Architecture in .net 6.

Comment: you question is not clear to me. you are talking about API then you are saying MVC . do you mean by API's with controllers ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've written, you have a couple options.

MVC is a front-end design pattern.  For backend development, you could create a Web API project, which would give you the ability to create models and controllers similar to MVC.  You would not create views with Web API as there is no UI.

Alternatively, and especially if it's a smaller project where scalability is not a concern, you could create an MVC project representing the whole app and include the backend code there rather than creating a separate backend project.  In this case you'd have models and controllers driving the UI, but not the backend.